# Как запушить отредаченный коммит?

Tags: git

Вот моя история коммитов:

```
75fe599 (HEAD) update catalog temp late, add catalog style
d133d8b ДО РЕДИЗАЙНА
b1a4b79 (origin/master, master) add catalog template
568863a add CatalogModel, ImageModel, CatalogAdmin, ImageAdmin
90b717b Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/saypinkx/shop
21e3b1d add tests for base and edit templates
f24623f Create README
a2c6d1b added login
e73db7e added verify
1384941 add code-verification
```

Я сделал еще один коммит после коммита d133, позже принял решение вернутся на него и продолжать работу в нем.
Перешел непосредственно туда, сделал все необходимое, закомитил.
Но, как я понял, git автоматически создает вторую ветку, для отредаченныех коммитов не считая последний.
git status выдал мне следующее `

```
HEAD detached from d133d8b`
```

git branch выдал:

```
* (HEAD detached from d133d8b)
  master
```

Все таки я нахожусь на ветке мастер, но куда тогда отправится мой коммит ?
или он просто отредактируется?
я решил продолжать работу с отредаченного коммита, но запушить так, чтобы этот коммит стал ластовым не могу, выдает:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

Какими должны быть мои действия? Удалить последний коммит и попробывать запушить? или создать отдельную ветку и смержить главную с ней? Второй вариант мне кажется проблематичным, возможны конфликты.

Comment: Возможно важное дополнение - мой последний коммит в удаленном репозитории b1a

Comment: Вы находитесь в detached HEAD, а не в ветке master. Вам нужно на текущем коммите создать новую ветку или сбросить существующую (например, master) на этот коммит. Если вы попытаетесь переключиться на другую ветку, текущие доработки будут потеряны.

Comment: `текущие доработки будут потеряны` - нет, их просто съест рефлог.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout master
git merge 75fe599
git push
```